# Dereferencing Pointers to manipulate the content of an address

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to change the value of an address in solitaire which provides the time.

Given the code below, the baseaddress + offset 0x97074 should point to another address with offset 0x50 and finally this address should point to the final address with offset x0C to change the timevalue.

However, solitaire crashes when I'm executing this operation.

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
sstream << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(hModule);
str = sstream.str();
BaseAddress = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(str.c_str());

//MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR) BaseAddress, "Adress", MB_OK); just some reminder
*(*(*(*(DWORD *) BaseAddress + (DWORD *) BASE_OFS_DEF ) + (DWORD *)TIME_OFS1_DEF ) + (DWORD *)TIME_OFS2_DEF) = 500;
```

Comment: "the baseaddress + offset 0x97074 should point to another address" ― says who?

Comment: as far as I know and seen from CE those address points to another address and finally this address is pointing to the time address. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would have not a shadow of an idea whether you are wrong or not.  Where did you get this information from? What's CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong, you are dereferencing your pointers before you add the offset and casting your offsets to pointers! I *think* this is what you want

```
*(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)(BaseAddress + BASE_OFS_DEF) + TIME_OFS1_DEF) + TIME_OFS2_DEF) = 500;
```

But you should really break that down a bit to help understand what's going on, e.g.

```
DWORD temp1 = *(DWORD*)(BaseAddress + BASE_OFS_DEF);
DWORD temp2 = *(DWORD*)(temp1 + TIME_OFS1_DEF);
*(DWORD*)(temp2 + TIME_OFS2_DEF) = 500;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but solitaire keeps crashing and I was just wondering why my BaseAddress returns only "1F4" without the "0x", does this affect anything? Do I have to add 0x before dereferencing to this address?

Comment: @Mostey No that's not the problem, 0x is just a convention for writing hexadecimal integer literals in C++ code. It's not something that means anything when your program is running. Trying breaking it down something like I showed, and see which line it crashes on. BTW I have no idea if what you are trying to do is right or not. I just tried to produce some code that matched your description.

Comment: @Mostey Just realised my 'simplified' code was bugged. I've editted to hopefully correct it.

Comment: Found out that it crashes because of the last line, both versions did not work, it's crashing when the actual time value is changed. Going to check the offsets now but for sure they're not the problem.